# I keep getting this error messages when try to use javadb

Tags: java, derby, javadb

i keep getting this error when i click to start. how to solve it?

Sat Mar 19 17:09:43 BRT 2022 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.

***WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called***

***WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl (file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_321/db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin/lib/derbynet.jar)***

***WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl***

***WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release***

Sat Mar 19 17:09:43 BRT 2022 : Apache Derby Servidor de Rede - 10.14.2.0 - (1828579) iniciado e pronto para aceitar conexões na porta 1527 em {3}

Answer (score 0):

The method `System.setSecurityManager` was deprecated in [Java 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_17), as noted in its [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#setSecurityManager(java.lang.SecurityManager)).

> **Deprecated, for removal: This API element is subject to removal in a future version.**
>
> This method is only useful in conjunction with the [Security Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SecurityManager.html), which is deprecated and subject to removal in a future release. Consequently, this method is also deprecated and subject to removal. There is no replacement for the Security Manager or this method.

I suggest you try the [latest version of Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/) to see if the problem is still there. Currently that would be 10.15.2.0 versus your 10.14.2.0. If still there, file an issue if not already filed.

**Not a pressing problem for you** while using Java 17. But in a future version of Java, removal of that feature will presumably break a calling app like Derby.

Answer (score 0):

For now, you can ignore it.

But for the future, you should look to get an updated version of JavaDB/Derby that is explicitly compatible with the newer Java versions.

`SecurityManager` is deprecated since Java 17 and will be removed in one of the next versions. Obviously, this will affect also all methods that deal with instances of that class, like `System.setSecurityManager()`.

Comment: In my current project We are using this code     @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp ()
    {
        originalSecurityManager = System.getSecurityManager();
        System.
            setSecurityManager(new NoExitSecurityManager());
    } This method has been deprecated, Do we have any replacement for setSecurityManager method???

Comment: @PriyankaTaneja – refer to the documentation for `SecurityManager`: it will be removed without replacement. So remove that code from you tests, after you updated to a library that is not using `SecurityManager` any longer.